# Accessing the undo stack from Word Javascript API

Tags: ms-word, office-js

My Word add-in programmatically makes some changes to the user's document, sends that document to a remote endpoint, and then needs to undo those changes.

I don't see any references to the undo stack in the Javascript API documentation, though I've seen some mentions in online questions that seem to indicate that the undo stack is inaccessible via the API. Is this the case? Is there no way to perform an automated undo on these changes?

I've thought of a few workarounds, but none seem viable.

Copying the contents prior to the changes and then pasting it over the altered content won't work as any Content Controls seem to not persist in the pasted content.

Another potential solution would be to save a copy of the document, make the changes to this copy, send the copy and then delete it afterwards, all invisibly to the user. I don't see any functionality in the API that would allow for this though.

Failing all this, I'll need to track all the changes and then re-create the initial state one change at a time, which will be challenging. Any simpler solutions at all would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Since you're using an add-in, you are interacting with the user? I'd be inclined to request the user to turn on Track Changes, then when you're finished to reject all the changes. Or, pick up the entire document's OOXML, change and send *that* - leaving the original document untouched.

Comment: Interesting thoughts. I like the idea of editing the OOXML in-the-air so to speak, as it requires no interaction from the user, though it's not something I'm very familiar with. I'll take a look, thanks for the suggestion :)